# Empty result set when Joining two table with Non-match Foreign key

Tags: sql, linq

I am joining two tables using a foreign key. TABLE_1 might have a row with a null for the foreign key. Which means that when I join the two tables based on that foreign key I won't get results for it. My problem is that when I use JOIN two tables in LINQ, I get an empty result set.

I want to be able to get the row in TABLE_1 even if the JOIN result with no match with TABLE_2.

I tried to use DefaultIfEmpty in the join of TABLE_2, but I still get an empty result set. How can I join two tables and still get a result even if TABLE_1 contains a null in the foreign key which I use to JOIN the two table?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check [how to perform left outer joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)? You need [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397905.aspx) first to be able to do outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try left join from Table2 to Table1

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Table1> Table_1 = new List<Table1>();
        Table_1.Add(new Table1() { Id = 1, Name = "Lion" });
        Table_1.Add(new Table1() { Id = 2, Name = "Elephant" });


        List<Table2> Table_2 = new List<Table2>();
        Table_2.Add(new Table2() { Id = 1, Class = "Carnivorous" });
        Table_2.Add(new Table2() { Id = 2, Class = "Herbivorous" });
        Table_2.Add(new Table2() { Id = 3, Class = "Mammal" });
        Table_2.Add(new Table2() { Id = 4, Class = "Aquarious" });


        var result = (from a in Table_2
                      join b in Table_1
                      on a.Id equals b.Id into leftJoin
                      from c in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new { Id = a.Id, Name = c == null ? string.Empty : c.Name, Class = a.Class }
                   ).ToList();

        var abc = result;
    }
}

public class Table1
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class Table2
{
    public int Id;
    public string Class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try RIGHT JOIN if LEFT JOIN doesn't work.